# Error in Admin form

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

When I open products and categories at the catalog in the Magento admin panel, this exception appears. How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: you are change any .xml file ???

Comment: i just add live chat and add a .less file in theme blank and include it in default_head_blocks.xml. But i deleted file .less and css including line in file default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: post your this file code `default_head_blocks.xml`...